# How to backup the configuration of a cisco switch and ASA to an SMB windows share?

Tags: backup, cisco, configuration, switch, cisco-asa

How do I backup the configuration of a Cisco switch and ASA to an SMB Windows share? I have full enabled admin through SSH. what would be the full command to save it to an SMB share? Is it "show run, save as smb://user:pass@192.168.1.3/folder???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I use Kiwi CatTools to create regularly occurring jobs to back up all of my switches and routers to a Windows file share.

http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-cattools-overview/

Answer (score 3):

`show run` and save it to a text file.

Comment: In addition, look into Rancid (http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) if you want to automate this.

Comment: what would be the full command to save it to an SMB share? Is it "save as smb://user:pass@192.168.1.3/folder???

Comment: @IT_Fixr, that command will dump the configuration on your screen. If your SSH Client logs the session, you can refer to that file, otherwise Copy & Paste tends to work well.

Answer (score 0):

OP does not say whether there is a Linux or Unix box available, but the phrase "SMB Windows share" suggests there is. As ErikA notes rancid deserves a plug. Of course, rancid will not in itself push the config to an SMB share, but it will do version management and mail changes to concerned parties. A quick cron hack should take care of pushing the file to SMB.

Just remember not to have any cleartext passwords in your configs before you start mailing them around.

Comment: Just because the OP used the word "SMB" for Server Message Block does not imply anything about SaMBa being used.

Answer (score 0):

you can used cisco built in command 'archive' to backup router and switch configuration but you can only save the archived files to FTP, HTTP, HTTPS, RCP, SCP, TFTP locations. I configured a FTP site for my setup and you can configured it to create backup file after certain time interval or when Write Memory command is issued.